# SQL Server query only returns first 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, sql-server-2014

I can't figure this out , I run the statement in SQL Server management and it returns all record sets, but when I run the exact same statement through the code it always returns only the first data-set.

I have tried the same simple `SELECT` statement in SQL Fiddle and it works the way it should, what could possibly be the cause of this?

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8689e4/1) to demonstrate what I am trying to do

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM Table1
WHERE column2 = '1234';
```

The way the data should look,

```
|column1(nvarchar(50)) | column2(nvarchar(50))|
-----------------------------------------------
|Section1              | 1234                 |
|Section2              | 1234                 |
|Section3              | 1234                 |
|Section3              | 1234                 |
-----------------------------------------------
```

The way it ends up after running the code.

```
|column1(nvarchar(50)) | column2(nvarchar(50))|
-----------------------------------------------
|Section1              | 1234                 |    
-----------------------------------------------
```

The code I am using.

```
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString As String
    sConnString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;" & _
                                   "Data Source=190.190.10.XXX,1433;" & _
                                   "Initial Catalog=my_DB;" & _
                                   "User Id=sa;" & _
                                   "Password=my_Password;"

               Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
               Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset              
               conn.Open sConnString
         strSQL = "SELECT Section_Data, Words_Data FROM Words_TBL WHERE Words_Data = '1234'"                       
                            rs.Open strSQL
                            If rs.EOF = False Then
                                x = rs.GetRows
                            Else

                            For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
                                  Debug.Print x(i, 0)
                            Next i
```

Comment: can you show us your code ?

Comment: You've asked us to tell you why your code isn't working, without including your code. How is it you think we can help?

Comment: My bad, I was supposed to put it in. Will do now.

Comment: Are you using ADO  / a recordset to get this data?

Comment: @iliketocode, updated code

Comment: What do you then do with `x` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams, I loop through the array.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, so maybe something with your display code?  Have you looked at `x` in the Watch window ?

Comment: @TimWilliams. Yes, and it shows only one record. In other functions the  select statements work fine, so I know the code is OK, not to mention the exact same  SQL code in Server management pulls all the data.

Comment: What happens if you change your query to `SELECT count(*) FROM Words_TBL WHERE Words_Data = '1234' ` ?  Do you get the expected number ?

Comment: @TimWilliams, it brings back `7`. So something is going on with the select???

Comment: Is your code *exactly* as posted - any lines left out?

Comment: @TimWilliams. No lines left out. Like I said before the same code gets thousands of lines of data from other tables, but this table will only return one. I will add the loop I am using.

Comment: For an array returned from from GetRows, the first dimension is *Columns* - second dimension is *Rows*, so it's your *display* code which is faulty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use the GetRows method to copy records from a Recordset into a
>   two-dimensional array. The **first subscript identifies the field and
>   the second identifies the record number**. The array variable is
>   automatically dimensioned to the correct size when the GetRows method
>   returns the data.

```
For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
    Debug.Print x(i, 0)
Next i
```

should be

```
For i = LBound(x, 2) To UBound(x, 2)
    Debug.Print x(0, i)
Next i
```

Comment: I can't believe this, I must not have my head screwed on, I was using the loop for a worksheet array, instead of the Get-rows array. I have hundreds of these statements using the GetRows array and I was so focused on SQL statement I forgot about the loop. Thanks, that fixed it. Rep for you Tim.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the CopyFromRecordset method to copy all data to a range. Much quicker, but you do need to loop through all field names first to create the headings.